# Shell script to automate the installation of cpan modules

Tags: linux, shell, cpan

I am writing a shell script to automate the installation of `cpan` (Comprehensive Perl Archive Network) modules.

```
#!/bin/bash
perl -MCPAN -e shell
o conf make_arg -I/"$PWD"
o conf make_install_arg -I/"$PWD"
```

The first command is being executed and it enters into the cpan shell, but the later commands are not detected. I think the later commands are not being executed as it is a different shell.
Any leads on this is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are writing a bash script, and `o conf ....` is not a bash command.

You could remote control the CPAN shell, by either

- providing all the input in a file, from where you redirect the stdin, i.e. `perl -MCPAN -e shell <my_commands.txt`. Note that this will fail, if the CPAN shell clears the input buffer after each command (I don't think that it does, but it could be).
- Write a [expect](http://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html) script
- Use your favorite programming language and use the Telnet protocol to steer the CPAN shell; since this is about Perl, you could use Perl's `Net::Telnet` module.
- Since the CPAN shell is written in Perl, I guess you can also write the whole thing completely in Perl, using the features which already there in the CPAN module. I would start by looking at the source code of the CPAN module to study, how the commands (for instance `conf`) are handled in Perl. After all, the CPAN shell is only one of the features of this module, although this is of course the one which people usually use.

Comment: Thanks for the support. I tried the first suggestion your provided and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use `bash` [here documents](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html). Your script will look something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
perl -MCPAN -e shell <<END_OF_CPAN_COMMANDS
o conf make_arg -I/"$PWD"
o conf make_install_arg -I/"$PWD"
END_OF_CPAN_COMMANDS
```

You can add more commands before the final `END_OF_CPAN_COMMANDS`.